# embedding youtube video results in CORS error

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, youtube

i'm trying to embed a video in my ionic app, but errors shows up when the page is loaded:

```
GET https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?pcm2cms=yes&key=yt6&ei=5HE…QBGK&c=WEB&cver=1.20170425&cmo=pf=1&range=0-622&rn=15&playerretry=3&rbuf=0 404 (Not Found)

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?pcm2cms=yes&key=yt6&ei=5HE…QBGK&c=WEB&cver=1.20170425&cmo=pf=1&range=0-622&rn=15&playerretry=3&rbuf=0. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://www.youtube.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

here's my html code:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="{{video}}" ></iframe>
```

here's the controller.js code:

```
$scope.video =  "https://www.youtube.com/embed/RP-mvJE9EQM";
```

i added this in my app.js file:

```
$sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['self', new RegExp('^(http[s]?):\/\/(w{3}.)?youtube\.com/.+$')]);
```

and this in my config.xml file:

```
<allow-navigation href="*.youtube.com" />
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />
```

how should i go about solving this? am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Try with http instead https.
Also, try to put this line inside index.html

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src * data: 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *;">
</head>
```

Be careful when you are using it because it allows everything.
More information about Content Security Policy:

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp/

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the input. i added the line of code in index.html and used http but it's still not working tho.

Comment: The solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

i added:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

in config.xml